# How transform count of words into a list of actual words in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame with the frequency of each word:

```
d = {'Count' : pd.Series([2, 3, 5]), 'Term': pd.Series(['Cool', 'New', 'Very'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The Table (print df):

```
  Count     Term  
0   2       Cool  
1   3       New  
2   5       Very
```

However, I want to transform the literal frequency of each word into a list of words for each respective frequency in one column called 'Term':

The output would look like this:

```
c = {'Term': pd.Series(['Cool', 'Cool', 'New','New','New','Very', 'Very','Very','Very','Very'])}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(c)
print df_2


        Term 
0       Cool 
1       Cool    
2       New   
3       New   
4       New    
5       Very   
6       Very   
7       Very   
8       Very   
9       Very
```

Can someone help me build something scalable that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

IIUC `pandas` `repeat`

```
df.Term.repeat(df.Count)
Out[350]: 
0    Cool
0    Cool
1     New
1     New
1     New
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
Name: Term, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
>>> np.repeat(df.Term,df.Count)

0    Cool
0    Cool
1     New
1     New
1     New
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
2    Very
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was this easy! I tried various google iterations. Thank you!

Comment: @UlisesSotomayor pandas as numpy make our lives much easier ;}

Comment: how can I put this in a pandas df?

Comment: @UlisesSotomayor you can use .to_frame() at the end, or assign it to a new column (e.g. `df['new_col'] = np.repeat(df.Term,df.Count)`)